# CAML Query builder using oracle query

Tags: caml

Is there any tool for creating caml query.I know how to write in Oracle. I want to convert into caml query which i doesn't know. Please anyone help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great tool from the [BIWUG group](http://www.biwug.be/resources) for assistance in writing CAML when it comes to Sharepoint, their CAML Designer. It can help you craft the CAML you need for web services or object model.